# C#, How to count the variables that have values > 0

Tags: c#, winforms

In C#, I have some decimal variables with values > 0 and some equal to 0.  I get these decimals from number of different text boxes on a C# winform.

What is best practice for counting how many of them have values > 0?

If the count is > 12, The variables that have the lowest values, (only the values that are non-zero) should be changed to 0

Comment: Put the values in an array. This is horrible.

Comment: Why aren't you using an appropriate data structure (i.e. array or list)?

Comment: "...lowest 2 values = 0" the two decimals with the lowest value (e. g. 0 or 1 etc.) or the _first_ 2 decimals in your list/array?

Comment: When you say "lowest 2 values = 0" do you mean value1 & value 2, or do you mean the variables that have the lowest values (including zero values or only values that are non-zero)?

Comment: sorry the variables that have the lowest values (only values that are non-zero)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't an award-winning piece of object-oriented software engineering, but it should do the job:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var seq = Enumerable.Range(0, 12).Select(i => (decimal)i);
    Console.WriteLine(GetGreaterThanZero(seq));

    var arr = seq.ToArray();
    SetMinNull(arr);
    foreach(var n in arr)
        Console.WriteLine(n);
}

static int GetGreaterThanZero(IEnumerable<decimal> numbers)
{
    return numbers.Count(n => n > 0);
}

static void SetMinNull(decimal[] numbers)
{
    decimal min = numbers.Min();

    // edit: credits to daniel for this loop
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        if(numbers[i] == min) numbers[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

It uses collections. I'd recommend you to use them too, however. Using a lot of numbered different values is a code smell, and barely too handy I guess.

Comment: Couldn't you make your `SetMinNull` a lot simpler? `var min = numbers.Min(); for(int i = 0; i< numbers.Length; ++i) if(numbers[i] == min) numbers[i] = 0;`

Comment: Sorry I am New with Programming ,  I am getting these decimals from number of different text boxes... How can I use Array.

Comment: Use a `LinkedList<decimal>`, and `AddLast` the values one after another. Using `ToArray` you can then convert it to an array.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth You're right, edited my post (I misread the original post...).

Answer (score 6):

Don't use a long list of decimals, use an array of them:

```
decimal[] values = new decimal[17];
/*Populate the values array with data*/
int CountOfMoreThanZero = values.Count(v => v > 0);
```

Comment: Sorry I am New with Programming , I am getting these decimals from number of different text boxes... How can I use Array.

Comment: `values[0] = Convert.ToDecimal(Textbox1.Text);`